# How to save textarea text into excel format using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

When I am going to download textarea text into excel format then its changing its format to other non supported language. Text in english is working fine on desktop but when i am going to save file in phone browser it shows file is corrupted.. In hindi, marathi or other language its changing format to non supportive language. kindly give me solution that how to save textarea text to excel format. screenshot attached.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      (function() {
var saveAs=saveAs ||(typeof navigator!=="undefined"&&navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob&&navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob.bind(navigator))||(function(view){"use strict";if(typeof navigator!=="undefined"&&/MSIE [1-9]\./.test(navigator.userAgent)){return}var doc=view.document,get_URL=function(){return view.URL||view.webkitURL||view},save_link=doc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml","a"),can_use_save_link=!view.externalHost&&"download"in save_link,click=function(node){var event=doc.createEvent("MouseEvents");event.initMouseEvent("click",true,false,view,0,0,0,0,0,false,false,false,false,0,null);node.dispatchEvent(event)},webkit_req_fs=view.webkitRequestFileSystem,req_fs=view.requestFileSystem||webkit_req_fs||view.mozRequestFileSystem,throw_outside=function(ex){(view.setImmediate||view.setTimeout)(function(){throw ex},0)},force_saveable_type="application/octet-stream",fs_min_size=0,deletion_queue=[],process_deletion_queue=function(){var i=deletion_queue.length;while(i--){var file=deletion_queue[i];if(typeof file==="string"){get_URL().revokeObjectURL(file)}else{file.remove()}}deletion_queue.length=0;},dispatch=function(filesaver,event_types,event){event_types=[].concat(event_types);var i=event_types.length;while(i--){var listener=filesaver["on"+event_types[i]];if(typeof listener==="function"){try{listener.call(filesaver,event||filesaver)}catch(ex){throw_outside(ex)}}}},FileSaver=function(blob,name){var filesaver=this,type=blob.type,blob_changed=false,object_url,target_view,get_object_url=function(){var object_url=get_URL().createObjectURL(blob);deletion_queue.push(object_url);return object_url},dispatch_all=function(){dispatch(filesaver,"writestart progress write writeend".split(" "))},fs_error=function(){if(blob_changed||!object_url){object_url=get_object_url(blob)}if(target_view){target_view.location.href=object_url}else{window.open(object_url,"_blank")}filesaver.readyState=filesaver.DONE;dispatch_all()},abortable=function(func){return function(){if(filesaver.readyState!==filesaver.DONE){return func.apply(this,arguments)}}},create_if_not_found={create:true,exclusive:false},slice;filesaver.readyState=filesaver.INIT;if(!name){name="download"}if(can_use_save_link){object_url=get_object_url(blob);save_link.href=object_url;save_link.download=name;click(save_link);filesaver.readyState=filesaver.DONE;dispatch_all();return}if(view.chrome&&type&&type!==force_saveable_type){slice=blob.slice||blob.webkitSlice;blob=slice.call(blob,0,blob.size,force_saveable_type);blob_changed=true}if(webkit_req_fs&&name!=="download"){name+=".download"}if(type===force_saveable_type||webkit_req_fs){target_view=view}if(!req_fs){fs_error();return}fs_min_size+=blob.size;req_fs(view.TEMPORARY,fs_min_size,abortable(function(fs){fs.root.getDirectory("saved",create_if_not_found,abortable(function(dir){var save=function(){dir.getFile(name,create_if_not_found,abortable(function(file){file.createWriter(abortable(function(writer){writer.onwriteend=function(event){target_view.location.href=file.toURL();deletion_queue.push(file);filesaver.readyState=filesaver.DONE;dispatch(filesaver,"writeend",event)};writer.onerror=function(){var error=writer.error;if(error.code!==error.ABORT_ERR){fs_error()}};"writestart progress write abort".split(" ").forEach(function(event){writer["on"+event]=filesaver["on"+event]});writer.write(blob);filesaver.abort=function(){writer.abort();filesaver.readyState=filesaver.DONE};filesaver.readyState=filesaver.WRITING}),fs_error)}),fs_error)};dir.getFile(name,{create:false},abortable(function(file){file.remove();save()}),abortable(function(ex){if(ex.code===ex.NOT_FOUND_ERR){save()}else{fs_error()}}))}),fs_error)}),fs_error)},FS_proto=FileSaver.prototype,saveAs=function(blob,name){return new FileSaver(blob,name)};FS_proto.abort=function(){var filesaver=this;filesaver.readyState=filesaver.DONE;dispatch(filesaver,"abort")};FS_proto.readyState=FS_proto.INIT=0;FS_proto.WRITING=1;FS_proto.DONE=2;FS_proto.error=FS_proto.onwritestart=FS_proto.onprogress=FS_proto.onwrite=FS_proto.onabort=FS_proto.onerror=FS_proto.onwriteend=null;view.addEventListener("unload",process_deletion_queue,false);saveAs.unload=function(){process_deletion_queue();view.removeEventListener("unload",process_deletion_queue,false)};return saveAs}(typeof self!=="undefined"&&self||typeof window!=="undefined"&&window||this.content));if(typeof module!=="undefined"&&module!==null){module.exports=saveAs}else if((typeof define!=="undefined"&&define!==null)&&(define.amd!=null)){define([],function(){return saveAs})}String.prototype.endsWithAny=function(){var strArray=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),$this=this.toLowerCase().toString();for(var i=0;i<strArray.length;i+=1){if($this.indexOf(strArray[i],$this.length-strArray[i].length)!==-1){return true}}return false};var saveTextAs=saveTextAs||(function(textContent,fileName,charset){fileName=fileName||'download.xls';charset=charset||'utf-8';textContent=(textContent||'').replace(/\r?\n/g,"\r\n");if(saveAs&&Blob){var blob=new Blob([textContent],{type:"text/plain;charset="+charset});saveAs(blob,fileName);return true}else{var saveTxtWindow=window.frames.saveTxtWindow;if(!saveTxtWindow){saveTxtWindow=document.createElement('iframe');saveTxtWindow.id='saveTxtWindow';saveTxtWindow.style.display='none';document.body.insertBefore(saveTxtWindow,null);saveTxtWindow=window.frames.saveTxtWindow;if(!saveTxtWindow){saveTxtWindow=window.open('','_temp','width=100,height=100');if(!saveTxtWindow){window.alert('Sorry, download file could not be created.');return false}}}var doc=saveTxtWindow.document;doc.open('text/html','replace');doc.charset=charset;if(fileName.endsWithAny('.htm','.html')){doc.close();doc.body.innerHTML='\r\n'+textContent+'\r\n'}else{if(!fileName.endsWithAny('.xls')){fileName+='.xls'}doc.write(textContent);doc.close()}var retValue=doc.execCommand('SaveAs',null,fileName);saveTxtWindow.close();return retValue}});

/*----*/

var area = document.getElementById('input');
var link = document.getElementById('savetxt');

link.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    saveTextAs(area.value, 'keywords.xls');
}, false); })(); </script>
```

[image: File save in .xls]
[image: Showing text in other format]